# How to export a image to act file

Tags: c#, colors, palette, act

I'm trying to create a mini tool for my job. I'm using C# with Visual Studio 2010 to do that. Now I need to export an image to an act file.

Following here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmappalette.aspx

I wrote

```
class Palette : List<Color>
{
    public static Palette GetFromImage(String PathToImage)
    {
        //Load imgae
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = new Uri(PathToImage, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        image.EndInit();

        //Load palette
        BitmapPalette BitmapPalette = new BitmapPalette(image, 256);


        //Convert it to list of Color
        Palette pal = new Palette();
        for (int i = 0; i < BitmapPalette.Colors.Count; i++)
        {
            pal.Add(Color.FromArgb(BitmapPalette.Colors[i].R, BitmapPalette.Colors[i].G, BitmapPalette.Colors[i].B));
        }
        //Return the palette has been creatted
        return pal;
    }
```

This code has effected, but the order of all colors in the result did not same as the order of all colors when I export by photoshop. So, when I write all colors to a act file, the act file is not correct.

Anybody can help me.

Many thank

Comment: Would it be possible to share a snippet of an act file that you are producting, compared to a snippet of one that you are expecting?

Answer (score -1):

Act file is compilated binary file.

You cannot encode an act file.

Perhaps Photoshop can import a css file (as like palet)